# Loading bar process on a TCP connection

Tags: browser, tcp, cross-browser, single-page-application

So, from what I can tell from TCP packets (which comprises most of the traffic you will deal with in a browser), they are ordered, but without the upper bound.  Meaning, the packet header will say 'Package Number: 6', but not 'Package Number: 6/180'.

So, how can you give an accurate loading bar?  You can't calculate the current/max ratio because the max isn't there.

I am asking this in the context of downloading a large file like a movie to your file system, or just receiving some JSON blob in a single-page app.  In both cases, how can an accurate loading bar work?

I know that many SPAs use spinners without an explicit percentage, but some SPAs, like YouTube and Instagram, do use loading bars.

Comment: HTTP headers contain a `Content-Length`.

Comment: Does that mean the server serving that request calculates that and puts it in the header?  What if there are multiple network requests for one view in the SPA?  Furthermore, how does it know to change the loading bar while waiting for the server to even respond to the request from the SPA?

Answer (score 0):

At the TCP level there is neither a length of the transferred file know nor is there even a concept of a file - it is all just a byte stream which will likely be closed some time in the future. It is even possible that multiple actual files are transferred over this byte stream but none of this is known at the TCP level.

The knowledge which can be used for some progress bar comes from the application level instead. When downloading a file with HTTP (i.e the protocol typically used today) the server will on most cases send a `Content-length` field in the HTTP header which shows the ultimate length of the response. Since the client knows how much bytes were already received he can show the percentage of data received.

It is also similar for uploads where the client knows the length of the data to upload and knows how much data it has already sent. Note that the client does not know for sure how much the data has actually received. But the mechanism of TCP makes sure that there is also a limited window of bytes "in-flight" and that the client will only be able to send more data once the server has acknowledged enough previous data.

But note that such a progress meter is not possible in all cases. Even with HTTP the server is not required to send a length up-front. It can simply omit this information and close the TCP connection once all data are transferred. Or it can use chunked transfer encoding where it sends the data in smaller chunks prefixed by the length but the ultimate length of the response is not known up-front. In this case the browser cannot display a proper progress meter since no final length is known, it is therefore usually only shown that there is still some transfer in progress but not how much done the transfer is.

And this is only with the HTTP protocol. But other application protocols are similar in that there might be a length known up-front or might be not, in which case some progress meter might show the percentage transferred or might be not.